# Can 3n³+4n-5 == O(n²)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, code-analysis

Can I change the C value so high that 3n³+4n-5 == O(n²) would be true?
Example:
3n³+4n-5 <= 3000n²+4000n² == 7000n²
C=7000

Comment: I meant O(n²), sorry.

Comment: Where does C come from?

Comment: O(2) is the same as O(2*1), but you normally drop the coefficient in O notation. That said the answer o this question is "no".

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't. C has to be a constant that does not depend on n. If you make n large enough you will always be higher for any pre determined C.

Answer (score 5):

f(x)=O(g(x)); means that there exists a constant C such that -

> |f(x)|<=C.|g(x)| for all significantly large values of x.

so in your equation 3n³+4n-5 == O(n²) you will not find any constant number such that |3n³+4n-5|<=C.|n²|. Hence this case is not possible. but you will find a constant c such that |3n³+4n-5|<=C.|n³|. So

```
3n³+4n-5==O(n³)  is possible.
```

Answer (score 3):

The definition is that `f(x)` belongs to `O(g(x))` if and only if the limit `limsupx → ∞ (f(x)/g(x))` exists i.e. is not infinity. In short this means that there exists a constant `M`, such that value of `f(x)/g(x)` is never greater than `M`. Let's try this for your function: `f(x)/g(x)= (3n³+4n-5)/n²`. For simplicity you can think of this function growing approximately the same rate as `3n³/n²=3n`. I think it is quite obvious that this function is not limited by any constant. Thus no matter what constant you choose `(3n³+4n-5)/n²` will always become greater than it because this function grows indefinitely.